# Batch with Google Bigquery and Python

Tags: python, google-bigquery, gcloud

What's the most efficient way to perform a batch insert in python using Google Bigquery Api. I was tryng to perform a stream row using this [code](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery) on a large dataset (1 000 000 +) but it's taking a while to insert them. Is there a more efficient way to insert a large dataset in Python?

- The table already exists, and it has info.
- I have a list of 1 millon datapoints I want to insert
- I'd like to do it with Python, because I'll reuse the code many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Streaming (Insert All API) makes sense in your case
You rather should try [Load Job](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.load)
See python code example in [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage#loading_data_from_google_cloud_storage)