# Given a column of more than 600,000 URLS, how do I extract the top level domain name and find the ip addresses efficiently?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, bigdata, google-colaboratory

I am using Google Colaboratory and bigquery to query a table containing over 600,000 URLS.

I want to extract the top level domain name, find the ip addresses of the domain names and then insert the results into the same table.

Currently I am brute forcing the problem by querying the column of URL names.
Iterating through each URL and using the following functions to extract the relevant information. I then write each record to a csv, with the goal of using the CVS to insert a top level domain name column and ip address column to my table.

```py
#I defined these functions to extract top level domain and ip address

import socket
from urllib.parse import urlparse
#Function to extract top level domain
def extractTopLevel(url):
    return urlparse(url).hostname

#Function to get ip Address of top level domain
def ipAddr(url):
  try:
     ipAddr = socket.gethostbyname(url)
  except:
    return "None"
  return ipAddr
```

```py
#this is how I query my table with the URLs
#update the topLevel Domain column
from google.cloud import bigquery


# https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects
project_id = [projet_id]
client = bigquery.Client(project=project_id)

query = (
    "SELECT (URL,topLvlDomain, ipAddr) FROM characterizing_Web.adscape_urls "
)
query_job = client.query(
    query,
    # Location must match that of the dataset(s) referenced in the query.
    location="US",
)  # API request - starts the query
```

```py
#Here's how I write to csv

table_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id).table(table_id)
table = client.get_table(table_ref)  # API request
import csv

with open('domain_ip_topLvel.csv', mode='w') as gray_web:
    gray_web_writer = csv.writer(gray_web, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

    for row in query_job:  # API request - fetches results
      gray_web_writer.writerow([extractTopLevel(row[0]['_field_1']), ipAddr(extractTopLevel(row[0]['_field_1']))])
```

I would like to be able to call some sort of function on the query_job to extract the domain name and ip address more efficiently.

Comment: Related: [Batch insert with Google Bigquery and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39085925/18771)

Comment: @j rupel welcome to SO and thank you for asking. Can you explain what are the criteria to top-level domain and IP. Given this definition why can't you built it into your SQL?